# Can you pin a file to Quick access in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

Simple question: Can you pin a file to Quick access in Windows 10? I don't mean pinning to the application shortcut on the taskbar or pinning to the taskbar, I mean pinning a file to Quick access in File Explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I came across it when searching for the same answer so I want to post an answer for anyone else who stumbles across this.

[According to Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/can-you-pin-a-file-not-folder-to-the-quick-access/629dd965-5331-48f4-b3f1-7da94e774322), no, you cannot add a file to the Quick access.

There are alternatives that others have suggested (you can Google for those options), but they're not the same as adding a file to the Quick access.